# Apache Cordova: Difference between browser and www platform

Tags: apache, cordova, web, browser

If I type on my console:

```
cordova platform ls
```

I get the following list for platforms:

```
Installed platforms:
  
Available platforms: 
  android ~6.3.0
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0 (deprecated)
  browser ~5.0.0
  ios ~4.5.1
  osx ~4.0.1
  ubuntu ~4.3.4 (deprecated)
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~5.0.0
  www ^3.12.0
```

But I cannot understand the difference between `www` platform and `browser` platform. The both seem to me that serve the very same purpose: Run cordova apps via the web.

But on a second thought it may be something slightly different. What is the reason for the two platforms? As fas as I look on [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/) it says-documents mostly mobile platforms such as:

- Windows phone
- iOs
- Android
- Blackberry 10

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think `www` is a valid platform and it shows up in the list of available platforms because of a bug somewhere in the cordova-cli.

If you have a look at the [supported platforms of the latest docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/reference/cordova-cli/index.html#supported-platforms) there is no mention of `www`. I do not know where version `3.12.0` comes from exactly, but one thing related to cordova and this version I found is that the latest version of [cordova-app-hello-world](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-app-hello-world) is `3.12.0`. If it would be a valid platform there would also be a github repo for it which is not present. So I suggest you just use the browser platform.

Comment: Now tracked in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-14148 as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It could show if you are using ionic, www is the ionic build for ionic serve